# Why do I keep on getting an ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException?

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception

I am trying to program a program that mimics the actions of a vending machine for my CS class. I have a double array  stock that represents the the number of items at a particular "slot" [my vending machine is weird and is kinda like one long vending machine with 1 column of different items]. Here is my code so far:

```
public class VendingMachine
{
    // define fields here
    public static double itemPrice[];
    public static String[] itemName; 
    public static int stock[][];
    public static  int maxPerSlot;
    public static double cashAmmount;

    public VendingMachine(int numslots, int maxperslot, double cash)
    {   
        final  int numSlots = numslots;
        maxPerSlot = maxperslot;
        cashAmmount = cash;
        stock = new int[numSlots][0];

        itemPrice = new double[numSlots];
        itemName = new String[numSlots];

        // complete this method
    }

    public void setProduct(int slot, String product, double price)
    {   int Slot = slot;
        itemPrice[slot] = price; 
        itemName[slot] = product;
        stock[Slot][0] = 0; 

        //
    }

    public void restockProduct(String product, int quantity)
    {   
        String Product = product;
        int currentCapacity = quantity - maxPerSlot;
        for(int i = 0; i < stock.length; i++){
            if (itemName[i]==Product){
                for(;quantity <= maxPerSlot && currentCapacity != 0; quantity--)
                stock[i][0] += 1;
            }   
        }


        //Put # of products in slot that holds it and if that slot is full put the rest in the next 
        //availble slot that holds that product, if all full return error.
    }

    public double getCashOnHand()
    {
        return cashAmmount; // replace this line with your code
    }

    public int getQuantity(int slot)
    {
        return stock[slot][1]; // replace this line with your code
    }

    public int getQuantity(String product)
    {   int total = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i<itemName.length;i++){
            if (product == itemName[i]){
                total += stock[i][1];
            }
        }
        return total;
    }

    public boolean buyItem(int slot)
    {   int snum = slot;
        if (stock[snum][1] != 0){
            stock[snum][1]--;
        return true;
        } else {
        return false;} // replace this line with your code
    }
}
```

Every time I runException in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at VendingMachine.setProduct(VendingMachine.java:27)
    at vmd.main(vmd.java:9) this code though I get this error message:

Can someone here please explain to me why I continue to get this error? I mean the logic seems quite correct .

Comment: so you got an error coming from your main function, but you aren't going to include it in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem's here:

```
stock = new int[numSlots][0];
```

This defines an array of numSlot arrays with a length of 0 each.

Answer (score 1):

when you initialize stock in the constructor do this instead:

```
stock = new int[numSlots][1];
```

using 0 instead of 1 initializes an array of length 0!

Answer (score 0):

You allocate zero elements in the second dimension of `stock`,

```
stock = new int[numSlots][0];
```

so you get that exception when you try to access the element at index zero.

```
stock[Slot][0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
stock = new int[numSlots][0]; // <-- A length of zero? You want a one there.
```

Should be

```
stock = new int[numSlots][1]; // <-- like so. Or, if you really don't 
           // want to change your other code make it a 2.
           // But you'll leave memory unused, and you really should change it.
```

Everywhere else (where you have code like this) -

```
stock[slot][1] // <-- stock[INDEX][1] <--- should be 0.
```

Like this

```
stock[slot][0] // <-- all of the other accesses.
```

Answer (score 0):

Because this line:

```
stock = new int[numSlots][0];
```

allocates `stock` to be an array of arrays, and each of those arrays has length 0.  So you can't assign anything into those arrays (they don't have any elements to assign).  So when you do this:

```
    stock[Slot][0] = 0;
```

you will get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds`.  Remember that in Java, indexes start at 0, so if you want an array where the indexes go from 0 to N, you have to allocate the array with size N+1.